# How can I install my ionic app on my android phone?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm trying to install my ionic app on my android phone. I tried

> install my ionic app on my android phone

The app ran on my phone, but when I ran the same command to run a different app, the app was replaced on my mobile. How can I keep both? I don't intend to modify any of these apps, they are ready. I tried these commands as well:

> ionic cordova build android --prod --release

and

> ionic cordova run android --prod --release

I got this error message:

> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android --release
>   (exit code 1)

Comment: it's not normal that the second app replaces the first if they are different, do they have the same app ID? (the `<widget id` in config.xml). Also if you have trouble to install your app, you always have the solution to get the .apk file from "platforms/android/build/outputs/apk", copy to the phone and run it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it will overwrite the previous version. You can keep the both app using below way:

Check the `config.xml` file, and change the `id` of the app.

```
<widget id="new.app.id" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Now, it will be considered as a different app and will not replace the previous one.