# building two android applications with ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I currently have two applications. I have built both with Ionic Cordova Build Android then copied and installed app1 through copying the apk to my phone but then when i install app2 it would just replace app1. What should I do so that both apps would be accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are facing the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944036/how-can-i-install-my-ionic-app-on-my-android-phone/48944219#48944219). By default, it will overwrite the previous version. You need to give two different id while building the two app. You can achieve this using below way:

Check the `config.xml` file, and change the `id` of the app.

```
<widget id="new.app.id" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Now, it will be considered as a different app and will not replace the previous one.